# Operator logic wont work in PineScript / Tradingview

Tags: operators, operator-keyword, pine-script

I'm trying to create a script in tradingview's pine script that displays the NEXT AUD futures contract. I want it to be able to calculate what year it is, then add that year onto the end of the future's ticker.

For example, these year's June AUD future ticker = "6AM2020"
I could just reference this, but in a years time the new future will be "6AM2021)
Hence why I'd like the script to constantly check what year it is, then add 'found year' to the end of the ticker logic.

I keep getting this error however.

"Script 'TEST - Next AUD future' has been saved
Processing script...

line 10: Cannot call 'operator +' with arguments (const string, series[integer]); available overloads: +(const integer, const integer) => const integer; +(const float, const float) => const float; +(input integer, input integer) => input integer; +(input float, input float) => input float; +(integer, integer) => integer; +(float, float) => float; +(series[integer], series[integer]) => series[integer]; +(series[float], series[float]) => series[float]; +(const string, const string) => const string; +(input string, input string) => input string; +(string, string) => string; +(series[string], series[string]) => series[string]; +(integer) => integer; +(float) => float; +(input integer) => input integer; +(input float) => input float; +(const integer) => const integer; +(const float) => const float; +(series[integer]) => series[integer]; +(series[float]) => series[float];
line 14: Undeclared identifier 'march_ticker';
line 18: Undeclared identifier 'march'

Script 'TEST - Next AUD Future' has been saved "

Code -

```
//@version=4
study(title="Next AUD Future", overlay=true)


// References current bar year
ticker_year = year


// Builds the desired ticker using the correct year as above
june_ticker = ("CME" + ":" + "6AM" + ticker_year)


// Creates a series using the ticker thats built above
june = security(june_ticker, timeframe.period, close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)


// Plots the series above
plot(june, title="June", color=color.aqua, title='June', linewidth=1, transp=0)
```

Code -

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't ask the same question in multiple forums. You risk getting different volunteers helping you concurrently. Your question was answered in the Pine Script chat on TV.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF. Yes, thanks for your help there. I only discovered your feed after posting this. Will close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

@PineCoders-LucF Provided this workaround on their support chat for anyone interested.

```
//@version=4
study("")
r     = timeframe.period
v     = close
y     = year(timenow)
s2020 = security("CME:6AM2020", r, v)
s2021 = security("CME:6AM2021", r, v)
s2022 = security("CME:6AM2022", r, v)
s2023 = security("CME:6AM2023", r, v)
s2024 = security("CME:6AM2024", r, v)
s     = y == 2020 ? s2020 : y == 2021 ? s2021 : y == 2022 ? s2022 : y == 2023 ? s2023 : y == 2024 ? s2024 : na
plot(s)
```